# Connection to SVN repositories fails after updates to NAS Synology DS710+

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, nas

I can no longer connect to repositories on my NAS Synology DS710+ using my SVN client. It used to work, (as we always say). The server (NAS) GUI indicated there were some packages that need updating.
I clicked yes, and after the updates, I could not connect to the SVN repositories any longer.
Thes packages are just updates to apps installed by default on server.

I get different message depending on if I try access or edit:

```
Browsing error: E210004: Handshake failed, data stream ended unexpectedly.
```

```
Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'svn//71.138.95.180/DeWalch'
Network connection closed unexpectedly.
```

I can still login to the NAS and browse around but cannot connect to the svn//71.138.95.180

Synology indicated the DSM software on the NAS is no longer supported, so they cannot help me.

I used Syncro SVN for years, and it also worked with TortoiseSVN.

Any help appreciated.

PS. I noticed there are many SVN connections related to authentication, but this seemed different.